# Ruby inline storage with gets command line support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Newbie to ruby, tried to play around with ruby script with ruby execute file. Like rails want to store an object in ruby and it should display to me.

```
ruby test.rb

puts "Welcome to BookDetails"
puts "1:Add"
puts "2:Delete"
puts "3:Update"
puts "4:View"
puts "5:Exist"
print "Enter your choice:"
  grade = gets.chomp
  emp = []
  i= 0 

  case grade
   when "1"
    emp[i] = Hash.new
    puts "Enter empname:"
    emp[i][:empname] = STDIN.gets
    puts "Enter emp email:"
    emp[i][:empemail] = STDIN.gets
    puts "Enter emp phno:"
    emp[i][:empphno] = STDIN.gets
    i= i +1  
    puts emp
   when "2"
    puts 'Enter the row to be deleted:'
   $delete = STDIN.gets
   when "3"
    puts 'update the row:'
   $update = STDIN.gets
   when  "4"
    puts 'view:'  
   when "5"
    puts 'exist:'
   else
    puts "You just making it up!"
   end
```

Now when i run ruby test.rb, it executes everything and get the numbers from command line but at last it comes out without showing the added object. It should exit only when am giving 5.

Till user choose 5 it shouldn't exit the interface.User can choose #1 and add the details and choose #4 to view the the details whatever added.

Comment: *"Ruby inline storage"* / *"store an object in ruby"* / *"store the object in-line"* - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Do you want to "loop" the interface until the user chooses to exit? What is supposed to happen when the user chooses #5?

Comment: Till user choose 5 it shouldn't exit the interface.User can choose #1 and add the details and choose #4 to view the the details whatever added.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that the script will exit after leaving the case statement. How have you actually tried to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has a [`loop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) method that *"repeatedly executes the block"*:

```
loop do
  print "Enter your choice: "

  case gets.to_i
  when 1
    # ...
  when 2
    # ...
  when 3
    # ...
  when 4
    # ...
  when 5
    break  # <- 'break' exits the loop
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems,

there's no loop for accepting additional input... after you enter '1' the program ends.

You could do

request_to_exit = false

```
until request_to_exit
  case grade
  ---
  when '5'
    request_to_exit = true
  else
   ...
  end
end
```

Another problem is that when you do

```
grade = gets.chomp
  emp = []
```

You are wiping out all employees (setting to an empty array) after you accept the `grade` (what action to perform)

The `emp = []` should be before the `until request_to_exit` starts.

That should help you progress in your project.

Comment: Or just use `emp ||= []` in place.

Comment: yep, @Substantial, good point. Unless OP wants the employee array explicitly initialised before the `until` loop.